# Prerequisite Installer Fails at Filter Pack 2.0

Tags: prerequisites

One of the servers where I am installing SP2010 continues to fail when running the Prerequisite Installer.
It seems not to like the Filter Pack 2.0.  I even attempted to download and install it separately but it fails with a detailed message "The installation of this package failed" and nothing shows up in the event log.

```
• Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role: configured successfully
• Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client: installed successfully
• Hotfix for Microsoft Windows (KB976462): installed successfully
• Windows Identity Foundation (KB974405): installed successfully
• Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x64): installed successfully
• Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5: installed successfully
• Microsoft Filter Pack 2.0: installation error
• Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services ADOMD.NET: Installation skipped
• Microsoft Server Speech Platform Runtime (x64): Installation skipped (optional component)
• Microsoft Server Speech Recognition Language - TELE(en-US): Installation skipped (optional component)
• SQL 2008 R2 Reporting Services SharePoint 2010 Add-in: Installation skipped (optional component)
```

Here is a snippet from the PrerequisiteInstaller Log:

```
2011-04-11 16:48:26 - Installing Microsoft Filter Pack 2.0
2011-04-11 16:48:26 - "C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe" /i "E:\PrerequisiteInstallerFiles\FilterPack\FilterPack.msi" /quiet /norestart REINSTALLMODE=vomus
2011-04-11 16:48:27 - Install process returned (0X654=1620)
2011-04-11 16:48:27 - [In HRESULT format] (0X80070654=-2147023276)
2011-04-11 16:48:27 - Last return code (0X654=1620)
2011-04-11 16:48:27 - Error: The tool was unable to install Microsoft Filter Pack 2.0.
2011-04-11 16:48:27 - Last return code (0X654=1620)
2011-04-11 16:48:27 - Options for further diagnostics: 1. Look up the return code value 2. Download the prerequisite manually and verify size downloaded by the prerequisite installer. 3. Install the prerequisite manually from the given location without any command line options.
2011-04-11 16:48:27 - Cannot retry
```

Answer (score 6):

Clear your temp files, and then re-download the 64-bit version of the filter pack from here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=5CD4DCD7-D3E6-4970-875E-ABA93459FBEE

Save it locally to your server, shift right-click the FilterPack64bit.exe and copy as path.  Click Start --> Run, type **CMD**, right-click the command prompt and run as administrator.

Right-click to paste the path to FilterPack64bit.exe, and then add **/log:c:\log.txt**.

The command prompt should look something like:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\FilterPack64bit.exe" /log
:c:\log.txt
```

Hit enter, wait for it to fail, and then go look at the log, which will have verbose information as to why it is failing.

Comment: The filter pack bits is inside prerequisiteinstaller folder on SharePoint 2010 server image. You don't need to download it.

Comment: Thanks for providing that link! The TechNet forum post about this issue only provided a link to the Filter Pack 1.0... Had a heck of a time figuring out the correct URL.

Answer (score 1):

I my case the problem was with Trend Micro Realtime Scanner preventing installation.  Stopping the service allowed the install to complete.